# Finding midnight from a stored variable

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page that will allow customers to enter a date/time and I want to be able to stored that variable and then add to that time until Midnight, store that as a second variable and pass it to my sql server. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: do you essentially want the difference in your current time until midnight? (ie a timespan)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do:

```
var midnightDateNExtDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;
  //AddDays moves time to next day
  // Date should omit the time and make it midnight
```

Do you mean midnight previous or next day?  Then, using this param, pass it to the stored procedure or query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference, you can do something like this and pass in the total seconds to sql server. This depends how you want to store this though on the sql end?

```
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date);
//do whatever with span.TotalSeconds
```

**EDIT**
It seems you also want to know how to send this into your procedure:

note this assumes connection strings setup in your app's config file. If not replace ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString with "server=whatever;uid;whatever;pwd=whatever;" for your testing (I recommend you dont embed them in code though)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString))

{


var midnight = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;

  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Proc_Whatever", connection))
  {
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MidnightDate", midnight));
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }

}
```

Comment: Adam, how would I go about storing that second value as a variable though? For example, I'm trying use code something like this:         If DateTime.TryParse(dateTextBox.Text, myDate) Then
                'Conversion was successful, the data is now in myDate
                newDate = myDate.AddDays(1)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow 100% do you mean store in a database? In that case you can just store the span.TotalSeconds in an int field in your DB. What are you trying to accomplish though from a higher level maybe there is a better way to attack the overall problem

Comment: Adam, I have a text box where users enter a start time, my stored procedure is for the time they entered it through the end of the day, but the user doesn't enter the end time, just the start time.

Comment: I want to dynamically create the end time, based upon the start time that the user enters into the text field.

Comment: the end time is just midnight right? do you need to know the difference (which is what I thought?) the midnight time is just from DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date, if thats all you need you can assign that to a DateTime variable and pass it into your proc

Comment: the end time is midnight, basically the SP that I have needs to know both start and end time (the end time will always be midnight of the day entered) I just don't know how to create the variable in my page, save it and pass it to my SP.